# What's alternative NSSortDescriptor in Java?

Tags: java, android

I hava ArrayList which is include Custom Data Class.

`ArrayList<MyData> list`

Custom Data class has several field

```
class MyData {
   private int num;
   private String name;

   etc....

   getter/setter...
}
```

I want to  sort List by field (ex:num)

Objecitive-C has NSSortDescriptor which can sort objects.

[NSSortDescriptor Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

is There alternative this? or other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement [Comparable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Comparable.html) or [Comparator](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Comparator.html) and use [Collections.sort()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%3CT%3E%29).

### Comparable

```
public class MyClass implements Comparable<MyClass>{
    public int x;

    public int compareTo(MyClass mc){
        return x - mc.x;
    }
}
```

### Comparator

```
public class MyClass{
    public int x;
}

public class MyClassComparator implements Comparator<MyClass>{
    public int compare(MyClass mc1, MyClass mc2){
        return mc1.x - mc2.x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Comparable and Comparator interface.. and the use Collection.sort().

You need to implement Comparable and Comparator interface, if you are using Collection of Custom Type(i.e not primitive types).

For detailed examples check http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/

Hope this post will be helpful to u.

Answer (score 1):

[java.util.Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) coupled with [java.util.Collection.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) should do the trick.

You could also have `MyData` implement [java.util.Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and use the other [sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) method, but that isn't quite as flexible.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing similar to `NSSortDescriptor` in Java: Java sorting uses the style that is more similar to the `sortUsingComparator:` method of the `NSMutableArray` class:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<MyData>() {
    // This is similar to the comparator block of Cocoa
    public int compare(MyData o1, MyData o2) {
        // Put the comparison code here
        ...
    }
});
```